# How to perform a Multivariate Polynomial Regression when output has stochastic behavior?

Tags: r, matlab

I have a experiment being simulated. This experiment has 3 parameters a,b,c (variables?) but the result, r, cannot be "predicted" as it has a stochastic component. In order to minimize the stochastic component I've run this experiment several times(n). So in resume I have n 4-tuples a,b,c,r where a,b,c are the same but r varies. And each batch of experiments is run with different values for a, b, c (k batches) making the complete data-set having k times n sets of 4-tuples.

I would like to find out the best polynomial fit for this data and how to compare them like:

fit1: [image] with [image]

fit2: [image] with [image]

fit3: some 3rd degree polynomial function and corresponding error

fit4: another 3rd degree (simpler) polynomial function and corresponding error

and so on...

This could be done with R or Matlab<sup>®</sup>. I've searched and found many examples but none handled same input values with different outputs.

I considered doing the multivariate polynomial regression n times adding some small delta to each parameter but I'd rather take a cleaner sollution before that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial regression should be able to handle stochastic simulations just fine. Just simulate `r`, `n` times, and perform a multivariate polynomial regression across all points you've simulated (I recommend [polyfitn()](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn)).

You'll have multiple `r` values for the same `[a,b,c]` but a well-fit curve should be able to estimate the true distribution.

In polyfitn it will look something like this

```
 n = 1000;
 a = rand(500,1);
 b = rand(500,1);
 c = rand(500,1);
 for n = 1:1000
    for i = 1:length(a)
       r(n,i) = foo(a,b,c);
    end
 end   

 my_functions = {'a^2 b^2 c^2  a  b  c',...};
 for fun_id = 1:length(my_functions)   
      p{f_id} = polyfitn(repmat([a,b,c],[n,1]),r(:),myfunctions{fun_id})
 end
```

It's not hard to iteratively/recursively generate a set of polynomial equations from a basis function; but for three variables there might not be a need to. Unless you have a specific reason for fitting higher order polynomials (planetary physics, particle physics, etc. physics), you shouldn't have too many functions to fit. It is generally not good practice to use higher-order polynomials to explain data unless you have a specific reason for doing so (risk of overfitting, sparse data inter-variable noise, more accurate non-linear methods).